# Has Julian Assange been missing since October 4th, 2016?

Tags: julian-assange

[FreedomHacker reported on November 29, 2016](https://freedomhacker.net/post-interview-still-asking-where-is-assange-wikileaks-claims-nothing-wrong-5224/):

> Now, Assange, the founder of Wikileaks, who appears to have vanished mid-October, hasn’t been seen alive or heard from since October 4th. Even after recent “interviews with Assange,” a large portion of supporters are still asking the question, where is Assange?

The Twitter hashtag [#proofoflife](https://twitter.com/hashtag/proofoflife?f=tweets&vertical=default&src=hash) gives links to:

- [The Outer Dark video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlpqYMpOOD0) (24-Dec-2016) conjectures that he might have been abducted to a brainwashing room with a gun to his head, with a list of claims about vaguely related incidents.
- [The Outer Dark video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anbn3kFL17k) (3-Dec-2016) claims an October 30th interview with John Pilger has "anomalies", conjecturing that it may have been generated by computer.
- [rt.com](https://www.rt.com/news/372210-assange-guardian-interview-fraud-greenwald/), an article about a mid December interview with a journalist from La Republica being misrepresented by The Guardian.

Has Julian Assange been missing from the Ecuadorian Embassy since October 4th?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) The claim on that site is not "Julian Assange is dead" - they are careful not to say that. The claim is "Julian Assange hasn't been seen by the public, and it is weird that no-one is bending over backwards to meet our increasing demands for evidence." If you want to ask if that is true, please focus the question.

Comment: The RT article says that a guardian article about an interview contained lies. It doesn't say anything about the interview not being authentic.

Comment: At least one website that used to claim that [Assange is dead](http://web.archive.org/web/20161220031751/http://assange.net/) has now r̶e̶t̶r̶a̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ [altered their claim](http://assange.net/) a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶p̶o̶l̶o̶g̶i̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶i̶r̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶i̶m̶s̶.

Comment: There’s the somewhat related, and potentially more credible claim, that Assange is no longer in control of the Wikileaks private keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The links you provide contain many ridiculous claims that need separate questions to address individually.

However, they also contain counter-evidence to the overarching claim.

- The first Outer Dark video mentions that actor/activist [Pamela Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamela_Anderson) visited him. Anderson was [reported](http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2016/10/17/worried-for-his-health-pamela-anderson-presents-julian-assange-vegan-meal.html) visiting him [in mid October](https://twitter.com/pamfoundation/status/790914144748892160) and also again in [mid-November](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3932036/Pamela-Anderson-cuts-sophisticated-figure-brings-snacks-WikiLeaks-founder-Julian-Assange-joked-vegan-treats-torture.html), well after the October 4th deadline.
- The rt.com link explains:

  > Assange spoke to the Italian newspaper’s correspondent Stefania Maurizi last week when she visited him in the Ecuadorian Embassy in London.

  That puts the interview in late-December.
- The first Outer Dark video mentions the Sean Hannity phone interview. This was [in December](http://variety.com/2017/tv/news/sean-hannity-julian-assange-fox-news-interview-1201951057/)

  > Most recently, in December, Assange called into Hannity’s radio show, in which the host gushed to Assange that “you’ve done us a favor” in exposing gaps in U.S. cybersecurity.

Hopefully, the face-to-face Hannity interview scheduled to be aired today (You aren't a publicist for Fox News, are you?) will put this to rest for all but the most hard-core conspiracy theorists.

Comment: Obviously a body double, or maybe computer retouching of the video :-)  I mean, how could you be sure it's him, barring fingerprints or genetic testing, and then there's always the chance that the fingerprints on file were replaced...